# Night in Minecraft Survival

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am a beginner in Minecraft and am not the best at defending myself at night when all the hostile mobs start spawning. I dig myself a three block deep hole in the ground and place a block above my head. This method wastes a lot of my time and I feel like I should be able to defend myself. Any tips about how to get ready for fighting monsters in the night during day?

Comment: Out of curiosity, but if you're hiding in the hole, why not craft a bed and just skip the night?

Comment: I’m sorry, I don’t understand. How do you get to skip the night? As I mentioned, I am a beginner and don’t know much about Minecraft.

Comment: Don't know about beds but happens to know nether fortress? Anyway, check [fandom](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Bed).

Comment: Craft a sword with stone, then find a cave and mine some iron in order to craft an armor.

Answer (score 2):

Hello Akshaya Gunnam and welcome !

You can **sleep** once the night begin to **skip to morning**. To craft generally and a bed in our case you will need a **crafting table**. Here are the steps:

1. Chop some **trees** to get logs. You will need **32 logs**. You can convert **4xlogs to Wooden Planks**.
2. Convert all logs to **8 Wooden Planks**.
3. Craft a crafting table (you will need **4 Wooden Planks** to craft a crafting table).
4. Kill some sheep to get at least **3 wool** from them
5. Use your crafting table from step 3 to create a bed using **3xWooden Planks** & **3xWool**

Comment: OP is asking for how to fight and what to do to get prepared for night, not how to skip.

Comment: That's true but it's the best alternative when you start the game. You can sleep a few nights until you are stronger and able to fight and survive night 

Comment: Thank you for the advice about the bed. I have always wondered what they do. Now, I can utilize my time better for mining and crafting!

Comment: Glad i could help :) you will get stronger day by day so you will finally be able to do more during the nights without having to skip to morning